# Difficulties reading text from URL in Android app

Tags: android, download

I am working on a small application where I am trying to read some text from a website, store the text in a variable, and then display that text in another activity. In my main activity I have a clickable label called "License Agreement" that when clicked, the app should read some text from a site, goto another activity, and then display that text for the user. However, each time I click on my label, my app force closes. Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void activity_license(View view) throws IOException{


        String stringBuffer;
        String text ="";

        URL url = new URL("http://something.something.com/LICENSE");

        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        while((stringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null){
            text += stringBuffer;
        }

        bufferReader.close();

        Intent licenseIntent = new Intent(this, LicenseActivity.class);
        licenseIntent.putExtra("LICENSE_AGREEMENT", text);
        startActivity(licenseIntent);
    }
}
```

And here is my second activity code, where I want to display the text ...

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LicenseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_license);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String licenseText = intent.getStringExtra("LICENSE_AGREEMENT");

        TextView lblText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblLicense);
        lblText.setText(licenseText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_license, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is my logcat, http://pastebin.com/zcvEVZZB

Answer (score 0):

```
// RETRIVE YOUR RESPONSE 
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {   
        Log.e("Loading Runnable Error converting result :", e.toString());
    }
```

Now Print this result as string.

Comment: I just checked my manifest, it's fine. LicenseActivity is there. I also put in my internet permission and everything :( ...

Comment: Using 'this' is not the problem. That I am sure of :P.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line + "\n");
}

try 
    intent.putExtra("licence",text.toString);
```

if this dont work try **HttpGet** in place of **HttpPost**......

Comment: where you are testing? in the device or in the emulator?